# Default method boolean methodname() not supported in API level lower than 24

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-7.0-nougat

i have changed my java compile version to 1_8.

```
  defaultConfig {
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
```

after that i have ran my project, got the below error, don't know what to do?

```
        Error:Default method boolean test(java.lang.Object null) not supported in Android API level less than 24
        Error:Default method void forEach(java.util.function.Consumer null) not supported in Android API level less than 24
        Error:Static method void com_google_common_collect_Multiset_lambda$forEachEntry$0(java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer null, com.google.common.collect.Multiset$Entry null) not supported in Android API level less than 24
        Error:Default method void forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer null) not supported in Android API level less than 24
        Error:Default method void addAll(java.lang.Iterable null) not supported in Android API level less than 24
        Error:Default method boolean enclosesAll(java.lang.Iterable null) not supported in Android API level less than 24
        Error:com.android.jack.JackAbortException
        Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException
        Error:Execution failed for task ':MyApp:compileDebugJavaWithJack'.
        > java.io.IOException: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException
```

Could any one please hep me out on this?

Comment: Have you enabled the Jack-Compiler? It is no longer supported and deprecated.

Comment: yes i have enabled jack. i have modified the code. plesae see it

Comment: @Christopher Is there a solution to resolve it?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: That's doesn't seem to be related to the usage of Jack or the new `desugar` toolchain but rather to a min SDK level below 24. An old device can't magically support new API that didn't exist when it was originally created. For example, your error messages mention the `Consumer` and `BiConsumer`interfaces from the package `java.util.function`. This package simply does not exist on devices below API level 24. While it's true that `desugar` supports Java 8 `language` features like default methods in interfaces it can't substitute for missing API implementations in the Android runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The `Jack`-Compiler is deprecated and should not be used. If you use Android Studio 3.0, you can simply switch to the new `desugar` feature, which supports Java 8 features, like `default`-methods for any `minSdkVersion`.

The features of `desugar` and how to switch from Jack to current solution is described here:

[Use Java 8 Language Features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html)

Comment: The OP's problem doesn't seem to be related to the usage of Jack but rather to a min SDK level below 24. The error messages mention the `Consumer` and `BiConsumer`interfaces from the package `java.util.function` which simply don't exist on devices below API level 24. So, I guess it's the usage of non-existing API that's the cause of the problem. `desugar` can't fix that.